# I have implemented a v2 invisible recaptcha in my website. I want to know for which users the challenge is rendered?

Tags: reactjs, invisible-recaptcha

```
async renderRecaptcha(id: string, cb: Function): Promise\<number\> {
    const widgetID = await window.grecaptcha.render(id, {
        sitekey: GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_CREDENTIALS.SITE_KEY,
        size: 'invisible',
        callback: cb,
    });
    return widgetID;
}

async executeRecaptcha(widgetID: number, action: string) {
    window.grecaptcha.execute(widgetID, { action });
}
```

Tried to add a callback in the second argument of execute like grecaptcha.execute(widgetID, { action, callback: onChallengeRender }) but it is giving error(Invalid argument).